# Is there a way to disable a hard drive in the UEFI?

Tags: hard-drive, multi-boot, uefi

BIOS allowed to disable specific hard drives. However I don't seem to find information about how to do it in UEFI. I would like to dual-boot, but I strongly prefer each Operating System (Which will be in different hard drives) are unaware/don't have access to the files of the other OS. Your answer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *BIOS allowed to disable specific hard drives.* No. BIOS disables only HDD detection (and building proper DOS drive table for it) during init. But HDD is available (any software - Windows OS, for example,- which uses its own procedures can access this HDD). Only physical detach guarantee from access possibility.

Comment: @Akina: No, firmware (or drivers) can often directly configure the SATA controller itself, for example, to pretend that a certain port is always disconnected – and that's permanent regardless of OS.

Comment: @grawity In case you describe the settings disables port/channel, not a device.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @camino Unfortunately, no! Sorry for the late reply, it's been a while since I last logged on.

Comment: @EderA. No worries, Thanks for the note!